# Can this type of function, defined on the closed unit disk, be analytically continued into the complex plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, analytic-functions, analytic-continuation

Let ${\Bbb D}:=\{z\in\Bbb C:|z|<1\}$ and $f:\overline{\Bbb D}\to\Bbb C$ be given by $f(z):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$, where the constants $a_n\in\Bbb C$ are such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n|$ is convergent but, for any given $x>1$, the quantity $|a_n|x^n$ is unbounded as $n\to\infty$. Can $f$ be analytically continued into the complex plane and, if so, what further conditions on the $a_n$ are known that will ensure this?

Comment: Your title doesn't quite match the question. Saying $f$ is analytic on the closed disk means it is analytic at each point of the unit circle ("analytic at $z$" means "differentiable on *some neighborhood* of $z$"). I.e. It has some taylor expansion about each of those points. So the answer to the title is yes, in every direction. But the actual problem does not assume analycity on the unit circle..

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you. I hope that the title is OK now.

Comment: It's good. It wasn't that big of a deal, but it did mislead me for a bit until I realized you hadn't assumed analycity on the circle in the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions imply that the convergence radius of the power series of $f$ centered at $0$ is $1$. This means that $f$ cannot be analytically extended to a full neighborhood of $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$.

There are examples of functions that cannot be analytically continued to any larger set than $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10831/example-of-continuous-function-that-is-analytic-on-the-interior-but-cannot-be-an) Mathoverflow answer for examples. My favorite one given there is

$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{n!}}{n^2}.
$$

Comment: To supplement Pjotr5's comments, Hadamard proved that the radius of convergence of a power series in $\Bbb C$ extends to the nearest singularity of the function. So $f(z)$ must have a singularity on the unit circle, which is why $f$ cannot be extended to a full neighborhood of $\overline{\Bbb D}$, as that would include the singularity. However, it may be extensible in some directions. Just not all of them. Or, as in the example, it may not be extensible in any direction.

Comment: @PaulSinclair  The condition that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty|a_n|$ is convergent implies that  $$\left|\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n\right|\leqslant\sum_{n=0}^\infty|a_n|$$ on $|z|=1$. That is, $f$ has no singularity on the unit circle.

Comment: @JohnBentin - perhaps I am using "singularity" more loosely than you understand it. I meant simply a point where the function is not analytic. It can be defined at the point, even in a neighborhood of the point. But every neighborhood of the point will have at least one point in it where the function is not differentiable. This is what Hadamard proved. The radius of convergence is always as large as it can be. To be any larger would include a non-analytic point *inside* the radius of convergence, which cannot be. So your conditions require some point on the circle to not be analytic.

Comment: @PaulSinclair - Thank you for the further explanation. I think I get it now.

Comment: @JohnBentin - I should also be a little more specific, Hadamard's result was that an analytic function cannot be extended analytically to all points at the radius of convergence. If you take a power series about $0$ and define a function to be equal to it, except for some region inside the radius of convergence, contrary to the impression my previous comment gives, the radius of convergence of this new function about $0$ does not change just because it was modified. The r.o.c. extends to the limit where the function *can* be defined analytically, not to which it actually is defined.